# How to get the response body as a String using Spring Gateway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I need to get information from the response body of certain responses as a json string.
I have seen the following example of modifying it:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
        .route("rewrite_response_upper", r -> r.host("*.rewriteresponseupper.org")
            .filters(f -> f.prefixPath("/httpbin")
                .modifyResponseBody(String.class, String.class,
                    (exchange, s) -> Mono.just(s.toUpperCase()))).uri(uri)
        .build();
}
```

[GatewayFilter Factories](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__gatewayfilter_factories.html)

But how would I just log it as a string?
Can I do it in a custom filter?

Comment: I am asking a specific question, for a specific framework and library, the object that this method returns has nothing to do with the response body.

Comment: There is a reason why I posted that idea as a comment...

Comment: @D.Tomov Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Not yet, sorry. Decided on using different approach

Comment: What's the approch you used. @D.Tomov

Comment: One not using the body